# Is there a way to access Flutter resources from native code?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to use the main logo from Flutter resources in my native Android code — for example, to display a notification. As you know, in Android you usually get resources from `drawable` folder like this `R.drawable.icon`. But then I have to copy the icon to Android drawable folder as well. Maybe there is a way to access Flutter resources (read — assets) from native code?

Comment: tried to [analyze](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) the `.apk` file created by `flutter run` / `flutter build` tools? did you notice it contains `assets` folder in the root?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a nice section sort-of about this in the [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#sharing-assets-with-the-underlying-platform).

Given an asset "icons/heart.png", for android (since 1.22):

> FlutterLoader loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader();
>
> String key = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset("icons/heart.png");

For iOS (swift):

> let key = registrar.lookupKey(forAsset: "icons/heart.png");
>
> let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: nil)

For iOS (obj-c):

> NSString* key = [registrar lookupKeyForAsset:@"icons/heart.png"];
>
> NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:key
> ofType:nil];

For android previous to Flutter version 1.22 (deprecated):

> AssetManager assetManager = registrar.context().getAssets();
>
> String key = registrar.lookupKeyForAsset("icons/heart.png");
>
> AssetFileDescriptor fd = assetManager.openFd(key);

However, you won't be able to share a drawable item directly to flutter, and the main icon is a bit of a special case that you definitely can't share with flutter either. Flutter doesn't know what a 'drawable' is but rather deals with resources its own cross-platform way.

Comment: what if I'm not on a plugin but in the MainActivity? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65374762/how-to-access-flutter-assets-from-java

Comment: And how do you convert your AssetFileDescriptor  to a Drawable, or a resource?

Comment: PluginRegistry.Registrar is deprecated. Answer from @SurajNair contains the updated code.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE FOR NEW VERSION**

For flutter release 1.22 or above, **FlutterLoader** is only accessible via **FlutterInjector**.

**`import io.flutter.FlutterInjector;`**

```
 FlutterLoader loader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader();
 String key = loader.getLookupKeyForAsset("assets_file_name");
```

Comment: and then, how do turn your key to a Drawable?

Comment: The project I'm working on is using a deprecated package which gives error on the line `final FlutterLoader flutterLoader = FlutterLoader.getInstance()`, replacing it with your solution made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to get relative path of asset file.

Below is the helper method to access the file/image path from swift native code.

```
func flutterAssetLottieFilePath(imageName : String) -> String {
        var flutterViewController = FlutterViewController()
        flutterViewController = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds).rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let key = flutterViewController.lookupKey(forAsset:"assets/images/\(imageName).png")
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: key, ofType: nil)
        return path ?? ""
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of when I wrote this, the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) was out of date. On my version of flutter, **1.17.1** here is an **kotlin android** example with the necessary imports above:

```
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader
import java.io.InputStream

val myAssetPath : Sting = "assets/my_asset"
val assetLookupKey =  FlutterLoader.getInstance().getLookupKeyForAsset(myAssetPath)
val inputStream: InputStream = applicationContext.assets.open(assetLookupKey)

// Read in the file from the InputStream...
```

It should be noted that the value returned from this **getLookupKeyForAsset** method is usually your asset path, as included it on your **pubspec.yaml** under assets, simply prefixed with "flutter_assets/". So in the case of the above example, it would return **flutter_assets/assets/my_asset**