# How to access the app icon the right way on Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, appicon

I want to use the app icon of my app inside of my app with Flutter. Hope there is a better way than putting the app icon inside the assets folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered [Is there a way to access Flutter resources from native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339637/is-there-a-way-to-access-flutter-resources-from-native-code), Flutter can't access drawables. so it can't give access to app icon. just Add the app icon as an asset!