# Flutter - Play sound files from platform specific folders (e.g. android/app/src/main/res/raw for Android)

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio, flutter-local-notification

In my Flutter app, I've some custom sound files placed in `android/app/src/main/res/raw` to be used as notification tones. Now I want to play these sounds when user selects using [Just audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package. Not sure how to reference and play these files (or any resources from platform folders, for that matter). For now I had to copy them to assets folder and play from there which is not a good solution obviously.

Comment: Why would would assets be no good? And how did you play them from assets?

Comment: The notification package I'm using (https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications) doesn't support sound files from assets and require them to be placed in that specific location.

Comment: Hi Mohammad. Did you Find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

1- Specify the path in pubspec.yaml file like so:

```
assets:
  - android/app/src/main/res/raw/file_name.mp3
```

2- Load the file as an asset with the full path using [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) package like so:

```
player.setAsset('android/app/src/main/res/raw/file_name.mp3')
```

Answer (score 0):

For a raw resource, you can use:

```dart
AudioSource.uri(Uri('rawresource:///resourceId'))
```

Comment: How to use this to play a file located at `res/raw/abc.m4a`? There's no such Uri constructor as in answer. Tried with `Uri(scheme: 'rawresource', path: 'raw/abc')` and `Uri(scheme: 'rawresource', path: 'abc')` but got errors.

Comment: I wonder if this is even possible in Flutter as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56351291/1513694) _"However, you won't be able to share a drawable item directly to flutter"_

Comment: The resource name is `abc`, so you would use this: `Uri.parse('rawresource:///abc)`. The reason this should work is that just_audio passes on your URI directly to ExoPlayer which interprets it, and that is how ExoPlayer should interpret this URI. One exception is if your URI has the `asset` scheme. This will not be passed through to ExoPlayer, it will be intercepted by just_audio and will load the file from your flutter assets instead.

Comment: That gives following error:
`E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(29564):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.RawResourceDataSource$RawResourceDataSourceException: Resource identifier must be an integer.`

Comment: For further information, you can see the ExoPlayer documentation here: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/DefaultDataSource.html

just_audio will pass your URI directly to ExoPlayer and then that page explains how ExoPlayer interprets your resource URI.